# How to save pdf attachment from Outlook API to a file using python

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am using the Outlook API and got this response when I requested an attachment from a specific email:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('myname%40hotmail.com.au')/messages('AQMkADAwATMwMAItYTZiNi05ZDgxLTAwAi0wMAoAtytTDBXFHqNdTw8vNERkHALm9xdAw4PxPkb4h1HfN4XIAAAIBDAAAALm9xdAw4PxPkb4h1HfN4XIAAmBXCV8AAAA%3D')/attachments",
    "value": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
        "id": "AQMkADAwATMwMAItYTZiNi05ZDgxLTAwAi0wMAoARgAAAyyLyoTDBXFHqNdTw8vNERkHALm9xdAw4PxPkb4h1HfN4XIAAAIBDAAAALm9xdAw4PxPkb4h1HfN4XIAAmBXCV8AAAABEgAQAIqjEp9FM2tKv4ahCWsIb7w=",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-05-01T11:58:33Z",
        "name": "Testfile.pdf",
        "contentType": "application/pdf",
        "size": 1013696,
        "isInline": False,
        "contentId": "ffeefe77-9bab-4736-83a3-79d921d3907b@icloud.com",
        "contentLocation": None,
        "contentBytes": "JVBERi0xLjYKJeLj...
```

I'm showing only a small portion of the `contentBytes` value as its too long, but its the one I'm interested in.

I tried decoding the `contentBytes` value using the base64 module and got this (showing only a portion of the result)

```
%PDF-1.6\n%âãÏÓ\n68 0 obj<</Length 1121/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream\nH\x89¬WÛnÛ8\x10}×WÌÛÊ\x0f¡y\x11%1\x08\x0cÄn\x12´@Òl¬E±\x08\x8a\x85bÓ±x12Ý*SÉöïw(É\x89ÝjÓ@.\x0c[\x129\x9a3sfxH\x8fgs\n³9Ðæ\x03óÙ\x95C\x89\x84gðà\x12\x9cñ\x05ÎÞo\x9coÀ\x9ay\x06\x8c\x86ÄçL\x02c\x8a\x84\x8a+Xd\x8e\x9dÊ\x1c¡|¼¦ÎÜùÓ\x19[·\x8b\x8d}\x01?°YäÖ`....
```

How can I get to see the actual contents of the pdf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will write to a file. You can then open the file with a pdf reader

```
import json

jsondata=json.loads(outlook-response)
f = open(jsondata['name'], 'w+b')
f.write(base64.b64decode(jsondata['contentbytes']))
f.close()
```

Comment: Great I've got it working thanks for that! I had to change the write to file line to `f.write(base64.b64decode(jsondata['contentbytes']))` as it was throwing an error before. I couldn't edit the answer as it wasn't allowing me to do so. You can edit it and I'll tick it as solved. Cheers

Comment: Good to hear of your success. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: This also seems to be needed for these extensions: xslx, jpg, jpeg, gif, png